# Unable to retrieve metadata for a state store key in Kafka Streams

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

I'm trying to use Kafka Streams with a state store distributed among two instances. Here's how the store and the associated KTable are defined:

```
KTable<String, Double> userBalancesTable = kStreamBuilder.table(
        "balances-table",
        Consumed.with(String(), Double()),
        Materialized.<String, Double, KeyValueStore<Bytes, byte[]>>as(BALANCES_STORE).withKeySerde(String()).withValueSerde(Double())
);
```

Next, I have some stream processing logic which is aggregating some data to this `balance-table` KTable:

```
transactionsStream
        .leftJoin(...)
        ...
        .aggregate(...)
        .to("balances-table", Produced.with(String(), Double()));
```

And at some point I am, from a REST handler, querying the state store.

```
ReadOnlyKeyValueStore<String, Double> balances = streams.store(BALANCES_STORE, QueryableStoreTypes.<String, Double>keyValueStore());
return Optional.ofNullable(balances.get(userId)).orElse(0.0);
```

Which works perfectly - as long as I have a single stream processing instance.

Now, I'm adding a second instance (note: my topics all have 2 partititions). As explained in [the docs](https://kafka.apache.org/10/documentation/streams/developer-guide#streams_developer-guide_interactive-queries_discovery), the state store `BALANCES_STORE` is distributed among the instances based on the key of each record (in my case, the key is an user ID). Therefore, an instance must:

1. Make a call to `KafkaStreams#metadataForKey` to discover which instance is handling the part of the state store containing the key it wants to retrieve
2. Make a RPC (e.g. REST) call to this instance to retrieve it

**My problem is that the call to `KafkaStreams#metadataForKey` is always returning a null metadata object**. However, `KafkaStreams#allMetadataForStore()` is returning a metadata object containing the two instances. So it behaves like it doesn't know about the key I'm querying, although looking it up in the state stores works.

[image: Debug]

Additional note: my `application.server` property is correctly set.

Thank you!

Comment: Sounds like a bug. Maybe file a JIRA: https://issues.apache.org/jira/projects/KAFKA

Comment: Have you checked out the examples here: https://github.com/confluentinc/kafka-streams-examples The `KafakMusicExample` show the usage of state stores. Btw: why do you writer your aggregation result to a topic and read it back into a KTable? You can query the KTable returned by `aggregate` directly, thus, there is no reason to duplicate the state. `aggregate()` has an overload that allows you to specify the corresponding store name.

Comment: Probably a stupid suggestion since it works when there's one instance, but: are you serializing the key correctly?

Comment: Yes, the key is a simple string which I serialize with a string serdes.

Comment: Did this ever get worked out?

Comment: Nope, unfortunately.

Comment: Seeing a similar issue now. Was this ever resolved for you?